# What are scriptural reference of not getting angry at those who disrespect our religion?

Tags: mahabharata, philosophy

So basically there are lots of power currently and also they might be present in past too, which actually tries to insult our practice and scriptures, or else they will oppose our bhakti by many ways!

now there are two ways to deal with it, either to stay silent or to react, and my question is specific to reaction part
so

1. What are the prescribe way to react?
2. what reactions are valid and what are invalid?
3. there are no religions which predates hinduism so there might wont be any does and Donts but still there must be some scriptural guidelines about how to react when someone (person or power) goes against Dharma?

Comment: Do you protect God or does He protect you? Why would the Omnipotent need your protection?

Comment: Best is learn Dharma, Vedas. Follow it! There is no other way to defend dharma. How will you defend in the first place if you have no knowledge about it.

Comment: There is already one or two questions on how to handle those who insult . But in a nutshell dharma in such cases is to be upheld by those in power. Common man should not take law in hand.

Comment: How is Hinduism disrepected?